# JavaScript function - cannot call as not receiving variables through the function?

Tags: javascript

When I try to run the following function:

```
function saveUsername(wordOne, wordTwo, wordThree){

wordOne = wordOne.capitaliseFirstLetter();
wordTwo = wordOne.capitaliseFirstLetter();
wordThree = wordOne.capitaliseFirstLetter();
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'capitaliseFirstLetter' of undefined
```

It seems that the variable `wordOne` is undefined, this doesn't make sense as I have definitely assigned a string to it and am even outputting this into the console further up the page, before this function (saveUsername) is called. The console shows that the variable is stored just fine.

```
var wordOne = document.getElementById('droppedOne').innerHTML;
  console.log("Word one chosen = " + wordOne);
```

Is this an issue with the function *saveUsername* not getting the correct values of the variables?

Here is how saveUsername is called...

```
<div class="userNameButton" onclick="saveUsername(wordOne, wordTwo, wordThree)">
```

Here is how the values are initially stored:

```
function saveWord1(){
  var wordOne = document.getElementById('droppedOne').innerHTML;
}
```

**EDIT:** As per solution below in comments I have added `window` to globalise but now getting a different error:

```
function saveWord1(){
  window.wordOne = "test";
  var wordOne = document.getElementById('droppedOne').innerHTML;
  console.log("Word one chosen = " + wordOne);

<div class="userNameButton" onclick="saveUsername(wordOne, wordTwo, wordThree)">
```

***Uncaught TypeError: Object test has no method 'capitaliseFirstLetter'***

**Here is the capitalise function**. This function is placed above the `saveWord1` function.

```
function capitaliseFirstLetter(string)
{
    return string.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + string.slice(1);
}
```

Comment: Please post how you call the function. If you don't pass any arguments to the function, then the parameters will be `undefined`.

Comment: Ah, that must be it, I didn't pass them through at the onclick stage.

Comment: The only variables the code in the `onclick` attribute has access to are globals.

Comment: I assume you know that `capitaliseFirstLetter` isn't a native JS function. You need to have written it.

Comment: @andy yes, I have written it.

Comment: @cookiemonster I have posted the function where the variables are first set. Do this exist then only in the scope of that function? How do I ensure they are available outside the function?

Comment: Yes, using `var` creates a variable local to the function in which it was declared. To create globals, assign them as a property to `window`, though it's a good idea to keep all your globally accessible stuff in a single global namespace.

Comment: @cookiemonster I believe I have gloablised the variables correctly but am getting a different error now. Added to OP.

Comment: `window.wordOne` is a string. Strings don't have a `capitalizeFirstLetter` method. Do you have a function by that name? If so, is it reachable from within your `saveUsername()` function? If so, then `window.wordOne = capitalizeFirstLetter(window.wordOne);` is what I would assume the solution would be *(having not seen that function)*.

Comment: Yes, I do have a function by that name, but it won't run it. The function capitaliseFirstLetter is not inside the same function.

Comment: @Francesca: You're calling it as a method of a string. Functions don't automatically appear wherever you need them. You need to appropriately reference and use them as designed.

Comment: Sorry, I was using an example which did this. How would I run my capitalise function rather than as a method then?

Comment: @Francesca: Not sure. I don't know anything about how that function is designed or where it's located. If it needs to be accessible from anywhere in your application, then again you'd need to make it global. How it's to be used depends on how it's coded.

Comment: If I add it to the OP are you able to help?

Comment: The quality of my help depends entirely on the information presented. The more detail presented, the better I can advise.

Comment: I will add the capitalise function code to the OP. Sorry, I have previously been told that adding too much detail means that people don't read the question as easily so I try to not add details.

Comment: So then wordOne = capitalizeFirstLetter(wordOne);

Comment: @Francesca: If that function isn't nested inside another function, then the code I gave you in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640346/javascript-function-cannot-call-as-not-receiving-variables-through-the-functio?noredirect=1#comment34482560_22640346) should be all you need.

Comment: @cookiemonster thanks, that worked! If you put it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issues.

1. Event handlers assigned in HTML attributes can only access global variables, so `wordOne` must be globally accessible.
2. `capitalizeFirstLetter()` isn't a native methods on string objects, though it's possible to make it so. As it is, it's a global function that receives an argument, and returns the result, so you need to pass `wordOne` as an argument, and overwrite `wordOne` with the result.

---

Side note, if you're going to use global variables, it's a good idea to collect them all in a single namespace.

So at the top of your application, create a global object *(the namespace)*:

```
window.MyStuff = {};
```

Then every time you need to add or access one of your own globals, add it to *(or access it from)* that namespace.

```
function saveWord1(){
  MyStuff.wordOne = "test";
  var wordOne = document.getElementById('droppedOne').innerHTML;
  console.log("Word one chosen = " + wordOne);
```

---

```
<div class="userNameButton" onclick="saveUsername(MyStuff.wordOne, MyStuff.wordTwo, MyStuff.wordThree)">
```

---

```
function saveUsername(wordOne, wordTwo, wordThree) {

    MyStuff.wordOne = capitaliseFirstLetter(wordOne);
    MyStuff.wordTwo = capitaliseFirstLetter(wordTwo);
    MyStuff.wordThree = capitaliseFirstLetter(wordThree);
```

---

Note also that in the `saveUsername()` function, if it's always going to operate on the same 3 globals, then you really don't need to pass them.

```
function saveUsername() {

    MyStuff.wordOne = capitaliseFirstLetter(MyStuff.wordOne);
    MyStuff.wordTwo = capitaliseFirstLetter(MyStuff.wordTwo);
    MyStuff.wordThree = capitaliseFirstLetter(MyStuff.wordThree);
```